# VBA Run-time error 438 when saving a table as image

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save an image of an excel table. I am getting the following error: 
**Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method**

It's strange because when i am using a similar code to save the image of a chart it works totally fine, but I am getting an error in case writing a code to save image of table.

Here is the code that brings the above mentioned error:

```
Sub Table6()

Dim objTable As TableObject
Dim myTable As Table
Set objTable = Sheets("Sheet6").TableObjects("Table6")
Set myTable = objTable.Table
myFileName = "name.png"
On Error Resume Next
Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
On Error GoTo 0
myChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"

End Sub
```

Do you know what could cause this issue?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!
Nana

Comment: myChart is never defined and has no value.

Comment: Also naming your macro the same as a table name is not really a good idea. Table6 is a clumsy name anyway.

Comment: VBA is not exporting a table as an image. What is the right way of recognizing setting? My goal is to save the image of the table.

Answer (score 2):

The type name of a table is `ListObject`, not "TableObject".
You can paste the table's image into a temporary chart object and export it.

**Exporting any range as image**

Here's a general routine to export *any range* as image:

```
Sub ExportRangeAsImage(rng As Range, destPath As String)
    Dim ch As ChartObject
    Set ch = rng.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, rng.Width, rng.Height)
    rng.CopyPicture
    ch.Chart.Paste
    ch.Chart.Export destPath
    ch.Delete
End Sub
```

**Testing and usage**

Here's an example, exporting a table's image:

```
Sub ExportTable6()
    ExportRangeAsImage Worksheets("Sheet6").ListObjects("Table6").Range, _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Table6.png"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Because currently i don't know the basics of coding for VBA - What would be right way for me to code? Do i just attach the tow pieces together and attach to my original code?

Comment: You only add the `ExportRangeAsImage` routine to your code, as a general routine (add it into `Module1`). Then you can invoke it to export *any range you want* as an image, by specifying the range and the file' s path. The second snippet is just a usage example that exports your `Table6`.

Comment: Hey A.S.H, thanks for your suggested method, but I have searched online and found this another code which worked so i used it.

Comment: @NaneAmiryan, That's fine, but you should try this one as well, one day you'll need to copy any range as a picture, not only tables. Besides, I hope next time you will do your search before asking the question.